# How do I find this pattern via Regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a Textfile which consists of Name and Phonenumbers like:

```
"Name, Name, PhoneNumber"
"Name2, Name2, PhoneNumber"
```

The Phonenumber in the textfile is mixed, i.e.

```
+48347449384
001101010111
0232/328484
```

I need to find a Regex in Notepad++, which matches the name and Numbers which contains 3 sequential identical numbers and does not ends on 0,1 or 7.

My Regex so far looks like this:
^[a-zA-Z], [a-zA-Z], +? [0-9]* /? [^017]$

But how do I do those 3 sequential identical numbers in Notepad++?

Comment: what language are you using? Generally you want to create a match by passing in your string and your regex pattern, you can then extract capture groups.

Comment: I just need it for general, for example, I want to find it using Notepad++...
Having a txt file and I want to search for that one special number.

Comment: (\d)\1{2} - this should capture 3 sequential identical numbers. I don't about Notepad++, but it works in Sublime and Python.

Comment: For example, I use this site: http://regexr.com/

But how do I write it? where do I put that (\d)... to? after [0-9]* ?

Comment: yes. \d*(\d)\1{2}\d* - this would capture any number with 3 consecutive same digits. by the way, \d is shortcut for [0-9].

Comment: Okay, I get matches, but I want to negate out the ending numbers 0, 1 and 7, it still matches me lines with 0 at the end... How to fix?

(\+|\d*)(\d)\2{2}\d*[^017]

Is my regex right now

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :

^[a-zA-Z]+, [a-zA-Z]+, +?\d*(\d)\1{2}/?\d*[^017]$

Comment: I just forgot the stupid ^ and $... Thats why it didnt work, thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\,\s[a-zA-Z]+\,\s[\+\/\d]*(\d+)\1{2}[\+\/\d]*[^174]\"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6ZJgCi/2